# Linux whereis command still returns a result after uninstall...?

Tags: linux

OK, hopefully this is a quick one but I can't seem to locate the answer.

After I uninstall a program, the whereis command still returns a reference.

For example. Let's say I had ssmtp installed but then I decided to completely remove it.

Performing **whereis ssmtp** returns - **ssmtp:**

I understand that there isn't a path any more but this seems a bit messy. Is there a way to completely remove any reference to what was previously installed when using this command?

I did apt-get --purge remove so I'm a little lost...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call **whereis** with any string, it displays the passed string, followed by a colon, then the program and manual locations, eg:

```
$ whereis ls
ls: /bin/ls /usr/share/man/man1/ls.1.gz
```

If there is no matching program, it still shows the parameter and colon, but the locations are blank, eg:

```
$ whereis xyz
xyz:
```

This is what is happening in your case.

Comment: As an afterthought, you could create a script file **where**, containing `whereis "$@"|sed 's/:$/: not found/'`. This would then show `xyz: not found`. You could even put the full **whereis** path in the script and `alias whereis=where`.

Answer (score 1):

That isn't a result, that's how `whereis` works. You can feed it anything and it will echo it back to you along with a list of what it found - essentially `whereis` is now explaining that it *can't* find `ssmtp` any more.